# How can I create a confirm popup alert before submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to ask `Are you sure you want to delete this comment?` as a popup alert when the users clicks on the button. How ca do that?

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    // show a alert to the user contains "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"

    if ( /* he pressed "yes" */ ) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        deleteComment(id);
    } else {
        // nothing happens
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `confirm`?

Comment: @JaromandaX I can create a popup just for showing a message by `alert()` function.. but now I need to create a intelligent popup which there is two button in it `yes` and `no`.

Comment: have you tried `confirm`?

Comment: @JaromandaX ok I got it now .. it would be better if you write `()` in the end of `confirm` word to make it more clear for a newbie programmer like me. thanks

Comment: sorry about that, noticed you've been answering javascript questions for months, so didn't think you were a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    answer = confirm("Are you sure?")

    if (answer == true) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        deleteComment(id);
    } else {
        // nothing happens
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

if (confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    deleteComment(id);
} else {
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Super easy! Just assign the confirm dialog to a variable

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   // Show confirm dialog and assign to var
   var decision = confirm("-- your dialog here --");
   if ( decision ) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    deleteComment(id);
   } else {
    // nothing happens
   }
});
```

Since js is synchronous it will run the code line by line! The confirm dialog will block anything after it running.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is same as the three above answer. It will vary how you implements your logic.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

   if (confirm("your dialog here") === true ) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    deleteComment(id);
   } else {
    // nothing happens
   }
});
```